# How do you pull events from google calendar by location?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to pull Google calendar events by location.

I have a piece of script that searches events by a string filter, but I'd like to know if the .getEvents has a way to search events by location.

`var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(), new Date(endDate), {location: 'Wisconsin'});`

There does seem to be a 'location:' search function for creating events, but not sure there is one for .getEvents

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to first get all the events by start and end date, then loop through the array of events, and check each one for it's location.  The `CalendarEvent` Class has a `getLocation()` method.

```
function getEventsByLocation() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(), new Date(endDate));

  var = i;
  for (i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    var thisEvent = events[i];
    var thisLocation = thisEvent.getLocation();
    if (thisLocation === 'Wisconsin') {
      //To Do
      . . . . . Code here to do what you want
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A full text search will include the location field.

```js
  var events = cal.getEvents( now, then,
                              {search:"Wisconsin"});
```

Unfortunately, this might include events that don't have `location == "Wisconsin"`, but which have that text anywhere else. If that's a concern, the filter shown in Sandy's answer will remove them, but with a potential efficiency improvement due to a shorter starting list.

If your search term includes multiple words, like "Embarrass, Wisconsin", then each word must match, as if the space between them meant AND. If your locations are more than one word, then a search will be very effective.

#### Advanced Calendar API

In this case, not so advanced, since we can't search individual event fields. However, the same full-text search can be applied, using the `q` parameter with `Calendar.Events.list()`:

```js
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = getRelativeDate(0,0);
  var then = getRelativeDate(7,0); // A week out

  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    timeMax: then.toISOString(),
    q: "Embarrass Wisconsin"
  });
```

Note: `getRelativeDate()` comes from an example in the [Advanced Calendar Service docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).